Grease Pencil 3 and Python: get / set the active layer
In the previous Blender version (4.2), I used the following lines to go up one layer in Grease Pencil:
# Assume this is a valid Grease Pencil object
gp = bpy.context.active_object;

curr_layer_index = gp.data.layers.active_index;

if ( curr_layer_index < len( gp.data.layers ) - 1 ):
    gp.data.layers.active_index += 1;
    
    

The code for going down is the same, save for the last two lines:
if ( curr_layer_index > 0 ):
    gp.data.layers.active_index -= 1;
    
    

According to the Blender 4.3 docs page for migrating Grease Pencil scripts, the active index was previously obtained with:
# Blender 4.2
layer.active_index

and can now be identified with the following:
# Blender 4.3
layers.index(layers.active)

(Notice how the first example uses layer, singular, whereas my code, which I'm quite sure was functional up to the final 4.2 release, uses layers, plural.)
Looking at the class references:

the GreasePencil class does have a layers property, of type
GreasePencilLayers;
GreasePencilv3 also has a layers property, of type
GreasePencilv3Layers.

Neither of these layers properties has an index subproperty. The old version, naturally, does have active_index; the v3 version does not.
How can I get and set the active layer with Python in Grease Pencil 3?
Extra note: it appears that a layer's index in its GreasePencilv3Layers parent is determined by its position in the UI's layer stack, but I can't find confirmation of this anywhere in the docs. And I still need to know the active layer's index to increment or decrement it.

Get Active index of Grease Pencil v3
layers = ob.data.layers
active_layer =  layers.active
active_index = layers.find(active_layer.name)
print(active_index)

# Or
active_index = list(layers).index(active_layer)

Set Active from index
layers = ob.data.layers
layers.active = layers[0]

Move
layers = ob.data.layers
layers.move(layers[0], type="UP")

# move_top, move_bottom, ...
# https://docs.blender.org/api/4.3/bpy.types.GreasePencilv3Layers.html#bpy.types.GreasePencilv3Layers

In your case it becomes
gp = bpy.context.active_object
layers = gp.data.layers
curr_layer_index = layers.find(layers.active.name)

if ( curr_layer_index < len( gp.data.layers ) - 1 ):
    gp.data.layers.move(layers.active, type="UP")


Well that solves the immediate problem, thank you! I wasn't specifically trying to move a layer though, just change the selected one. Also, there is the matter of the docs and the 'layers.index(layers.active)' instruction. Do you happen to know how that is supposed to work? Did I miss something or are the docs just wrong?

The layers is not a list and needs to be converted to a list first: list(layers).index(layers.active)

Wow, that's... something I really wish I could have seen on the reference page. At any rate, that answers just about everything, so answer accepted, well done!
